# jquery load() method not working -- IE8

Tags: jquery, browser, load

So been fiddling around with this for a while now but still no luck.
I've tried changing jquery versions, tried doing the whole `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`, tried rearranging JS/jquery scripts, tried the no caching thing suggested by jquery website but still my `load()` doesn't work on IE8.

```
<a onclick="loadCont('canyou.php');">Can you help us</a>


function loadCont(file){
$j("#maincont").load(file);
alert(file);
return false;
}
```

As always it loads on every other browser except IE8. The `alert()` is there for IE8 debugging, and the file is passed successfully to the server with status 200 (checked with Fiddler2), its just not loaded into `#maincont`
I've tried different methods such as:

```
$j.ajaxSetup ({
            // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
    });

    // Bind ajax call to click
    $j('a.loadlink').click(function(e) {
            $j('#maincont').load($j(this).attr('href') + ' #filecont');  // Dynamically load content from URL in href
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

And commenting out all my other JS externel includes "styleswitcher.js and formcheck.js". I know the jQuery is working correctly as I use a jQuery drop down menu. At the moment my current code looks like this, which works fine on every other browser....

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $j("#mcfrnav li").hover(
            function(){ $j("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); }, 
            function() { } 
        );
    if (document.all) {
            $j("#mcfrnav li").hoverClass ("sfHover");
        }

    $j.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
        return this.each(function(){
            $j(this).hover( 
                function() { $j(this).addClass(c);  },
                function() { $j(this).removeClass(c); }
            );
        });
    };    
    });

function loadCont(file){
$j("#maincont").load(file);
}

</script>

 <script src="styleswitcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="formcheck.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function imgError(id){
id.src = "photos/noimg.png";
id.onerror = "";
return true;
}

</script>
```

All or any help about the code or replies appreciated. Many thanks to all replies.

EDIT: Still looking for a fix for this :(

Comment: use firebug to see if there are any errors

Comment: does the hover work? because i think the `documrnt.ready` should be written as `$j(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: yes the hover works fine in all browsers, i will however add the 'j' and check :)
*EDIT: added 'j', no change in loading content on IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using formcheck.js its based on mootools javascript if I'm not wrong. Please put your jQuery file on top and try.
Another thing you can do is instead of creating no conflict object you can directly `jQuery`. I've used formcheck and jQuery in a same page. Please refer [`http://www.mymegaenergy.com/enrollments`](http://www.mymegaenergy.com/enrollments) It should work fine if you do these things.

Comment: formcheck.js is a custom JS file I wrote and not part of a toolset, just using the same name, i didnt realise mootols used this name. tried but no change. thanks for your reply :)

Comment: can yo give me your page link? Such that i can try that. and let you know what the problem is...

Comment: Hello friend, Thanks for sharing your site with me. I've gone through your site. I found something unusual on line #24 on IE for $j("#mcfrnav li").hoverClass ("sfHover"); It throws an error Object doesn't support this property or method. and I've googled about this and found this link please go through it http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/294. I would like to suggest you to use css class :hover property why you want to manipulate with javascript.

Comment: This was a third party jquery script that i found online, its weird you think that would affect it as i commented all of this out and it still didn't work correctly.

Comment: Have you checked in IE debugger tool It does show the error messages if there is any. I've also seen there itself. That can be invoked by pressipng F12.

Comment: i get an error on line 24.... $j("#mcfrnav li").hover(. commenting this out of the code and refreshing gives me no errors at all, yet the content still doesnt load.... and the hover effect still works. this ones a head scratcher!!

Comment: re-cached the page and its definitely being commented out despite still working. hmmmm

Comment: Hi @ben have you uploaded the code which you've just commented that you've commented that line #24 but the same line is there in line #31. Please comment the line and update your code. I've rechecked your site.

Comment: line commented out. lins 30- 53

Comment: Hello Ben I've tried I'm not getting whats wrong with it, but when I've tried this jQuery ajax code I got the response. Please try this instead of load. 
function loadCont(file){
jQuery.ajax({
url:file,
success:function(response){
jQuery("#maincont").html(response);
}
});
}
Please try the ajax function which I've tried in IE console and I got the your file as response.
Lets finish this discussion.